# Is it possible to change Chrome's view-source behaviour to use the current request instead of starting a new one?

Tags: google-chrome

I like Firefox's behaviour of loading the source from the currently loaded webpage. Chrome, instead, starts a new request. This makes it especially hard to view source of POST-requests, for example, since every view-source request utilizes GET.

***Is there a way to change the way Google Chrome's view-source works, so that it does not initialize a new request?***

**EDIT,** ***little bit of clarification regarding the way Firefox works:***

Firefox does not initiate a new request when viewing the source. It does only after refreshing the page while viewing the source. It then respects the GET/POST of the request as well. When viewing the source of a page that is already loaded, it does not seem to initiate a new request.

Comment: are you just interested in the current POST submit? use the developer tools and not the source-view.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; in this case I am looking for the state of the HTML source code after the POST request. It is not something that is completely hindering me from working, but it would be nice to have the ability to customize this behaviour.

Comment: @Arjan it does only after refreshing the page while viewing the source. It then respects the GET/POST of the request as well. When viewing the source of a page that is already loaded, it does not seem to initialize a new request.

Comment: See this question: [How to prevent Chrome from refreshing page when viewing source?](http://superuser.com/questions/172928/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the way Google Chrome's view-source works, so that it does not initialize a new request?

No, this is the way Chrome works [by design.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4650)

> When you "view source", you're really
>   opening a new tab that opens the page 
>   again and displays the source rather
>   than renders the page. Many web pages
>   are  dynamic and modify their HTML
>   content (eg. using
>   JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest) so we 
>   cannot display the current HTML - this
>   is why a new request is made.
>
> If you want to view the current state
>   of a dynamic page, you should use the 
>   inspector. "File icon -> Developer ->
>   JavaScript console"
>
> **I don't see how this is a security bug
>   or a bug at all - the behavior is by
>   design -  closing as such.**

Comment: Maybe things are different on a Mac, or have meanwhile changed. The *when you "view source", you're really opening a new tab that opens the page again and displays the source rather than renders the page* is NOT true on my Mac, neither for GET, nor for POST. (Yes, I did fire up Wireshark to make sure. No additional requests after hitting Option-Command-U.)

Comment: ...but when doing a View Source after a POST, I do indeed see the source of the (earlier) GET...?!

Comment: Try to teach a CSS class using Chrome and I think you'll agree it's more than a bug - it's a feature designed to make CSS development impossible. It is completely useless to see the source code of some OTHER page that you aren't looking at. A re-load is another page, not the one you wanted the source from. GOOGLE needs to know this is stupid - comment not directed at poster.

Comment: @Arjan, Because it is **cached**. Remove your cache or disallow caching and you will see that view-source indeed issues a new request.

Comment: Crappy workaround posted on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/a/173323/128630 ... I wish it would just work like Firefox does.

Comment: Pretty stupid that I have to open FF just for this behavior, which is very essential during dev. Even viewing the DOM is a pain in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change the behavior of `view-source:` URLs, or the **View page source** command, you *can* get to the source as received for this page: first, open the Developer tools (WebKit's "Web Inspector"), found at **[image: Wrench]** > **Tools** > **Developer tools**. Now click on **Resources** and (if necessary) scroll down the list on the left until you find the resource of interest. And there you go: the source as it was transmitted in the original HTTP response.

Comment: No that reloads the source too. Fiddler can capture it.

Comment: And I dont see any 'Resources' anymore